# Unable to run cordova run android in IONIC project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I installed ionic in my Mac and created project using

> $ ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial

Now i run

```
$ cd MyIonicProject
$ ionic serve
```

Now it is serving successfully in browser working fine. So I would like to see the same in android mobile so tried using the below command,

> ionic cordova run android --prod --release

This is the pretty concise issue and i can't able to rectify my OSX error's below are the issues when i run above in my Mac..

```
 > cordova run android --release
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.2
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: spawn EACCES

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --release (exit code 1).

[17:54:52]  lint finished in 2.69 s
```

Please help me someone on how to rectify these error when running the IONIC project on Android natively.

Thanks,

Comment: what does `cordova run android --verbose` give?

Comment: Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home 
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.2
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle" -p /Users/username/Documents/IONIC/MyIonicProject/platforms/android wrapper -b /Users/username/Documents/IONIC/MyIonicProject/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
Error: spawn EACCES

Comment: weird I had the same issue for `build` this morning :P.. Would have been me posting this question

Comment: Is this a real device or emulator?

Comment: @Jaccs sorry.. corrected my answer. it was a bit confusing when I was trying to figure out

Answer (score 1):

I had run into a similar issue.<s>I had to set executable permissions in the android platform gradle.</s> Correction: It was actually executable permissions in the android gradle installation. It seems to be a reported issue [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2835) and the actual issue in cordova is tracked [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13495).

Run the command:

```
chmod -R +x <location_of_android_studo>/gradle/gradle-<version>/bin
```

NOTE: `-R` will run the command recursively from the given directory.

Comment: strange...  you wouldn't think this would be needed.  I haven't ever see this before.

Comment: @PhilipBrack corrected my answer since it was actually an issue with permissions in latest gradle installation. Turns out the issue is reported [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2835).