# spawn EACCES while building android application in ubuntu

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

When I updated Android studio to 3.0 and run my ionic application I am getting the following error. I have googled and found that `chmod` but I don't know where to use the command either in my project gradle or in the android studio gradle. can anyone help me in sorting this issue pls.

Error:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
[18:00:22] 'cordova-with-build' errored after 2.24 s
[18:00:22] Error in plugin "gulp-shell"
```

This is my android configuration

```
 Android version :  android 6.2.2
  Ionic version : 3.7.0
  Cordova version: 7.0.1
```

[Github link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2835)

> sudo chmod 755 "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle"

Comment: `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle` this path is application path in Mac not Ubuntu. You need to find the location where your Android Studio gradle is installed in your system

Comment: @SurajRao i have tried but still i am facing the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350972/4826457 tried what command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like npm permissions. "If you see an EACCES error when you try to install a package globally, read this chapter" [fixing-npm-permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).